# WpDataTable with PHP snippet

Tags: php, wordpress, export-to-excel

I am using WPDatatable (a wordpress plugin) to display tables on my WordPress site.

My task is to show the content of a child table `child` where the foreign key on the parent table `parent` is entered dynamically via a link, like

wwww.myWordPressSite/myChildTable/?parent_id=1

The plugin accepts different formatted data structures, I'm trying to use serialized php-array that I construct as desired using a `php` snippet to generate the desired data and format it correspondingly, as I have some column names in `parent` table.

Now, what I am stuck with, is how to use the snippet, along with the `parent_id` parameter, to create and show the `wpDataTable`... I though of `echo`-ing the table with it's name but then, I don't know how to set the serialized php-array as datasource...

Please note that the table must be read-only. Suggesting another plugin that would work is perfectly acceptable, but I must be able to export to Excel on demand!

Comment: How about showing some code.  Further, it'd be good to make it clear that WP Datatable is a WP plugin, and expects data structured in a specific format.

Comment: @cale_b my bad, added the wrong keywords... As for code - I have none to show as I don't know HOW to create the whole thing... I know how to create the desired `PHP` array and resialize it - the question is HOW to use this array as a DYNAMIC datasource.